# sudo is required to view manpages when using most as the pager

Tags: manpage, pager

I've installed `most` to be used as the default pager to view the man pages. `most` is exported as the `PAGER` in `.bashrc`. When I run a command like `man grep` I get the following error:

```
man: can't execute “most”: No such file or directory

man: command exited with status 255: sed -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/{ N; /^[[:space:]]*\n[[:space:]]*$/D; }' | LESS=-ix8RmPm Manual page grep(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$PM Manual page grep(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$ MAN_PN=grep(1) “most”
```

However, the following commands work without any issues.

- `man -P most grep`
- `man -P pager grep` <<< loads with most
- `sudo man grep` <<< works when command is run as root user

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

PS: I upgraded to 20.04 from 18.04

Comment: When I execute `PAGER=most man grep` on a system *without* `most`, I get the same error message except that `can't execute most: No such file or directory` does not have the typographical "smart" quotes around `“most”`. Is it possible you used smart quotes in the `PAGER` assignment in your `.bashrc` file? Please [edit] your question to include the relevant section of your `.bashrc`

Comment: that is correct. i removed the quotes and now its ok. Thanks. But why did it work when I used ```sudo``` or when I ran the command as root?

Comment: `sudo` performs an `env_reset` so would not be affected by your user's `PAGER` environment variable